# Transition from 100% to auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following: [**http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2491/**](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2491/)

I was wondering why the transition isn't working? What it's supposed to do is slide in the hidden element (which can be of variable width) to the right edge of the `.block` element, however, it just pops in.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.block .hidden {
  background: red;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}
.block:hover .hidden {
  transition: 1s;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="hidden">ABCDEFGHIJKL</div>
</div>
```

I think it has something to do with `left: auto` because if I change it `left: 50%`, it works, but not in the way I need it to.

Thanks.

Comment: it would be good to know what youre trying to achieve

Answer (score 5):

As you say you can't animate from `%` to `auto`. But to get the desire effect you can also use `transform` property. Try this:

```
.block .hidden {
    background: red;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform:translateX(100%);
    transition: 1s;
}

.block:hover .hidden {
    transition: 1s;
    transform:translateX(0)
}
```

Check the **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2492/)**

Answer (score 2):

Consider transitioning on `right`, from `-100%` to `0`:

```css
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px; /* shortened to fit in the "Run" window */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.block .hidden {
    background: red;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -100%;
    transition: 1s;
}

.block:hover .hidden {
    right: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="hidden">ABCDEFGHIJKL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice +1. also think about that Hoping the element will not be more larger than the container.

Comment: The problem with this is that we're hiding the element further than it needs to be hidden (just the right edge), which slows down the transition because it needs to travel further.

Answer (score 0):

For transition to work, you have to define the property you wish to change in **both** element states.
In your example it doesn't work because there is no common property between '.hidden' and ':hover' (you set the '**left**' property in '.hidden', and '**right**' property in ':hover')

If you instead use something like:

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.block .hidden {
    background: red;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -100%;
    transition: 1s;
}

.block:hover .hidden {
    transition: 1s;
    right: 0%;
}
```

It will work because we defined the '**right**' property in both states ('.hidden' and ':hover')